# Modelica: Class not found in scope

Tags: modelica, lib, openmodelica

I am trying to create my own GreenEnergy library in OpenModelica. I reproduced a similar structure of the library to Modelica Standard Library, but unfortunately receiving the next error:

```
...
[GreenEnergy.Validation.Wall: 5:3-5:312]: Class GreenEnergy.HeatTransfer.Components.Wall not found in scope GreenEnergy.Validation.Wall.
...
```

I have next file(and its content) structure:

**GreenEnergy**

- package.mo

  ```
  within ;
  package GreenEnergy
  extends Modelica.Icons.Package;
  end GreenEnergy;
  ```
- HeatTransfer

  - package.mo

  ```
  within GreenEnergy;
  package HeatTransfer
  extends Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer;
  end HeatTransfer;
  ```

  - Components

    - package.mo

    ```
    within GreenEnergy.HeatTransfer;
    package Components
    extends Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components;
    end Components;
    ```

    - Wall.mo

    ```
    within GreenEnergy.HeatTransfer.Components;

    model Wall

    import Modelica.Units.SI;
    import Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer;

    parameter SI.Area area = 1 "Wall area";
    parameter SI.Length thickness = 0.5 "Thickness of wall";
    parameter SI.Density density = 2000 "Wall density";
    parameter SI.ThermalConductivity thermal_conductivity = 0.62 
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity";
    parameter SI.SpecificHeatCapacity specific_heat_capacity = 800 
    "Wall material specific heat capacity";
    parameter SI.Temperature initial_temperature = 288.15 "Initial 
    temperature of wall";

    final constant SI.HeatCapacity heat_capacity = area * thickness * 
    density * specific_heat_capacity;
    final constant SI.CoefficientOfHeatTransfer 
    coefficient_of_heat_transfer = thermal_conductivity * thickness;
    final constant SI.ThermalConductance thermal_conductance = area * 
    coefficient_of_heat_transfer;

    HeatTransfer.Components.HeatCapacitor heatCapacitor(C = 
    heat_capacity, T(displayUnit = "degC", fixed = true, start = 
    initial_temperature)) annotation(Placement(visible = true, 
    transformation(origin = {1, -33}, extent = {{-23, -23}, {23, 23}}, 
    rotation = 180)));
    HeatTransfer.Components.ThermalConductor thermalConductorOuter(G = 
    thermal_conductance / 2) annotation(Placement(visible = true, 
    transformation(origin = {-56, 0}, extent = {{-18, -18}, {18, 18}}, 
    rotation = 0)));
    HeatTransfer.Components.ThermalConductor thermalConductorInner(G = 
    thermal_conductance / 2) annotation(Placement(visible = true, 
    transformation(origin = {56, 0}, extent = {{-18, -18}, {18, 18}}, 
    rotation = 0)));
    HeatTransfer.Interfaces.HeatPort_a port_a 
    annotation(Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = 
    {-100, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), 
    iconTransformation(origin = {-66, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 
    10}}, rotation = 0)));
    HeatTransfer.Interfaces.HeatPort_b port_b 
    annotation(Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {100, 
    0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), 
    iconTransformation(origin = {62, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 
    10}}, rotation = 0)));
    HeatTransfer.Celsius.TemperatureSensor temperatureSensor 
    annotation(Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {58, 
    52}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput temperature 
    annotation(Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {106, 
    52}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), 
    iconTransformation(origin = {0, -102}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 
    10}}, rotation = -90)));

    equation

    connect(thermalConductorOuter.port_b, heatCapacitor.port) 
    annotation(Line(points = {{-38, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, -10}}, color = 
    {191, 0, 0}, smooth = Smooth.Bezier));

    connect(thermalConductorInner.port_a, heatCapacitor.port) 
    annotation(Line(points = {{38, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, -10}}, color = 
    {191, 0, 0}, smooth = Smooth.Bezier));

    connect(port_a, thermalConductorOuter.port_a) 
    annotation(Line(points = {{-100, 0}, {-74, 0}}, color = {191, 0, 
    0}));

    connect(thermalConductorInner.port_b, port_b) 
    annotation(Line(points = {{74, 0}, {100, 0}}, color = {191, 0, 
    0}));

    connect(temperatureSensor.port, heatCapacitor.port) 
    annotation(Line(points = {{48, 52}, {2, 52}, {2, -10}}, color = 
    {191, 0, 0}, smooth = Smooth.Bezier));

    connect(temperatureSensor.T, temperature) annotation(Line(points = 
    {{68, 52}, {106, 52}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
    annotation(Icon(graphics = {Rectangle(origin = {-1.75, -0.54}, 
    fillColor = {142, 142, 142}, fillPattern = FillPattern.Backward, 
    extent = {{-63.75, 99.46}, {63.75, -99.46}}), Text(origin = {-3, 
    83}, lineColor = {85, 0, 255}, extent = {{-59, 25}, {59, -25}}, 
    textString = "%name"), Text(origin = {-15, -83}, lineColor = {170, 
    0, 0}, extent = {{-13, 21}, {13, -21}}, textString = "T"), 
    Text(origin = {-34, 2}, extent = {{-20, 12}, {20, -12}}, 
    textString = "outer"), Text(origin = {29, 2}, extent = {{-27, 10}, 
    {27, -10}}, textString = "inner"), Text(origin = {-2, 57}, extent 
    = {{-60, 19}, {60, -19}}, textString = "C=%heat_capacity"), 
    Text(origin = {22, 33}, extent = {{-84, 25}, {84, -25}}, 
    textString = "G=%thermal_conductance")}));

    end Wall;
    ```
- Validation

  - package.mo

  ```
  within GreenEnergy;
  package Validation
  extends Modelica.Icons.ExamplesPackage;
  end Validation;
  ```

  - Wall.mo

  ```
  within GreenEnergy.Validation;

  model Wall

    extends Modelica.Icons.Example;

    GreenEnergy.HeatTransfer.Components.Wall wall1(area = 1, 
     density(displayUnit = "kg/m3") = 1, initial_temperature = 
     274.15, 
     specific_heat_capacity = 1, thermal_conductivity = 1, thickness 
     = 1)

     annotation(Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = 
     {0, 0}, 
     extent = {{-45, -45}, {45, 45}}, rotation = 0)));

    //Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedTemperature 
    fixedTemperature(T = 283.15)  annotation(
    //Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-76, 22}, 
    extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

    //Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedTemperature 
    fixedTemperature1(T = 303.15)  annotation(
    //Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {68, 22}, 
    extent 
    = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));

    Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedTemperature 
    fixedTemperature annotation(Placement(visible = true, 
    transformation(origin = {-70, -0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 
    10}}, 
    rotation = 0)));

    Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedTemperature 
    fixedTemperature1 annotation(Placement(visible = true, 
    transformation(origin = {70, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 
    10}}, 
    rotation = -180)));

    equation

    connect(fixedTemperature.port, wall1.port_a) 
    annotation(Line(visible 
    = true, origin = {-44.85, -0}, points = {{-15.15, -0}, {15.15, 
    0}}, 
    color = {191, 0, 0}));

    connect(wall1.port_b, fixedTemperature1.port) 
    annotation(Line(visible = true, origin = {43.95, 0}, points = 
    {{-16.05, 0}, {16.05, 0}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));

    end Wall;
  ```

And then I am trying to run Validation.Wall model...
So, why I am receiving error that component is not found in scope?

Best

Comment: Since the problem seems to be the first Wall-class it's best if you include that fully as well.

Comment: @HansOlsson not very readable, but added all the code. thx.

Comment: Generally, it's strange... I downloaded the PhotoVoltaics library a just copied my files to its similar structure, and it works.

Comment: @HansOlsson after many attempts I have got the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the next packages code:

```
extends Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer;
```

and

```
extends Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components;
```

When I replaced those lines with the simpler line:

```
extends Modelica.Icons.Package;
```

Problem disappeared.

`Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer` package contains those lines at the beginning:

```
within Modelica.Thermal;
```

but `Modelica.Icons.Package` is declared in a different way by using `partial` keyword. More details about partial keyword [here](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/ModelicaReference.%27partial%27.html).

Best.

Comment: Your explanation makes not so much sense. The `within` statement and `partial` are something completely different, which cannot come in conflict with each other. But removing those `extends` is definitely good, as you usually don't want to inherit everything from another package.

Comment: @marco ok, I will try to precise it.. I am just a beginner at Modelica Language but it seems that you can safely derive class from partial classes(and they do not include within statement), and in my case problem was that I was deriving from `Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components` which is not partial(and includes `within` statement) and I think it had complication on namespace lookup and result in error.

Comment: The `within` statement defines where the class resides in the hierarchy. It is used to map Modelica packages to files and folder. It has no influence on the model itself.